# File exists on main thread but background thread says it does not (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, avmutablecomposition

I am exporting an `AVMutableComposition` video to a temporary location and then successfully transferring it into the Camera Roll. Upon exporting, I check on the **main thread** if the returned Camera Roll URL stored as `let videoPath` exists with:

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: videoPath) {
   print("FILE AVAILABLE")
} else {
   print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
}
```

It does. So I place it in an `AVPlayer` and it plays all good. So then I want to upload it to my web server so I cast that same URL as contents of a `Data` object in a **background thread** and before doing so I run the same `FileManager.default.fileExists` and this time the console says `FILE NOT AVAILABLE` which obviously makes the `Data` try constructor **fail**.

Before calling the background thread function, I even check on the main thread if the file exists and **it does** but then in the background it says **it does not**.

Now what is the strangest part and why I came to SO is because after this initial file check fails, I move to a different view which can run that same background function and on that second time (all subsequent times after the first failure) the console shows `FILE AVAILABLE` and does its thing.

What is going on here?

Comment: Tripple check `videoPath` is the same for all calls.

Comment: @shallowThought I just have by printing the url out to the console and they were indeed the same

Comment: Threading Considerations - the methods of the shared FileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anyone else has this issue, I solved it through the following manner:

Instead of checking for the `videoPath` and creating the `Data` object in the background thread (and risking it not being able to detect it for reasons beyond me), I just created the `Data` object on the **main thread upon export** and simply pass the created `Data` object to the function for uploading. Simple and took care of the problem!

Sometimes the best solution is not to figure out the system, but to beat it.